# Bessel function first order

Tags: bessel-functions

I am solving a physics problem in which I've found an integral of this kind. I have seen a similar expression for the Bessel function, nevertheless the limits are different, how could I evaluate this integral?

$$
\int\limits_{-a}^{2\pi-a}e^{ixcos(u)}du\,.
$$

Thank you for your help

Comment: As it is written, the integral is $0$.

Comment: I think you have $$e^{ix}\int_{-a}^{2 \pi -a} \cos u du=0$$ no?

Comment: Sorry! I have already edited the integral! I made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos u$ is $2\pi$-periodic and because you integrate on an interval with $2\pi$ amplitude, you can shift the limits and integrate between 0 and $2\pi$:
$$ I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ix\cos u}du$$
Then changing $u\to2\pi-u$ leaves the integrand inchanged, so
$$I=2\int_0^{\pi}e^{ix\cos u}du$$
Using the [integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E2) for $J_0(z)$,
$$I=2\pi J_0(x)$$